Unresolved reference error at Terraform moved block code
I have a api-gateway resource created with the below definition in Terraform main.tf file
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "test-api" { }

Now I have changed the resource reference name as "prod-api" as below
 resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "prod-api" { }

To avoid deletion of existing api gateway because of name change from test-api to prod-api, only to update the resource reference name in state file, I tried using moved block
moved {
  from     = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-api
  to       = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.prod-api
}

But in the above moved block, the from line is throwing error stating
unresolved reference test-api
Since the old resource reference name "test-api" is not present in current configuration as it is changed to "prod-api", I am not sure how to provide the reference for "test-api" in from line.
I tried defining a variable and referencing using it but that didn't work.
Could you please let me know on how to provide the resource reference for the name that doesn't exist in the current code configuration?

One thing did come to mind, did you run terraform plan first?

Yeah ran the terraform plan, now I have provided entire module address of the resource that is being changed in from and to of moved block and ran terraform plan. But in Terraform plan it is still destroying the existing resource and creating as new resource

Wait, this is inside of a module? Was it before?

Yeah there is a module defined for this api-gateway.
I made use of the module address and provided the same in from and to as below:
from: module.test-api-module.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test-api
to: module.test-api-module.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.prod-api

The moved block code was not provided inside a module. I have provided moved block code in main.tf of api-gateway config
